# StreamBuilder child widget interaction

Tags: dart, flutter

The following code builds and runs as intended--when a user types something, an error message gets shown until the string passes an email validation format.

```
Widget emailField(){
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: bloc.emailStream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    return TextField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'you@example.com',
        labelText: 'E-mail address',
        errorText: snapshot.error
      ),
      onChanged: (newValue){
        bloc.updateEmail(newValue);
      },
    );
  },
);
```

}

I am told that when the stream changes, the `builder` field gets called which rebuilds the TextField.  But if that is the case, shouldn't the TextField always have a blank string?  What happens instead is it retains its value.

I am trying to understand what exactly is happening here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not really, If you look at the code of the `TextField` , you'll find it's a `StatefulWidget`, so its has a State and the state keep the value.

```
 class TextField extends StatefulWidget
```

Additionally you can use the `TextEditingController` to handle(get/clear/set) the data of the `TextField` , if you don't provide a `TextEditingController` it will be created by default as you can see in the source code.

```
 @override
 void initState() {
   super.initState();
   if (widget.controller == null)
     _controller = TextEditingController();
 }
```

You can find more information here: https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes/

Answer (score 0):

`TextField` **widget** is newly created, but it's corresponding **element** is reused/recyled (and so is it state).

Here's a pretty good explanation from the creator: https://youtu.be/AqCMFXEmf3w?t=99